# 32-Bit Application runs out of Memory

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, 32bit-64bit

I have a memory problem. Since 12 Years we use in our software (C++, 32Bit) own made tables to store data.
The Tables are stored on disk. When we want to use data of it, they are loaded in Memory and stay there. 
Some tables are very big, they have more than 2 Million rows. When we load them into memory
they up to 400MB. Due to 32bit and memory fragmentation we can actually load maximum 2 such tables int
o memory before other operations did't get enough of memory.

The software is installed on more the 3000 clients. The OS on the clients is win7-win10 (32Bit and 64Bit) and some insignificant XP and Vista Systems

So we discussed a good (fast, propper ) way to get out of this problem. Here are some ideas:

- switching to 64Bit
- switching from our own tables to sqlite or ejdb
- opening every table in an own process and comunicate with the process to get data of the table
- extend our own tables that thay can read directly from disk

All Ideas are more or less propper, practicable and fast (implementing speed and execution speed). The
advantages and disadvantages of every idea ist very complicated and will go beyond the scope of this.

Has someone another good idea to solve this problem?

---

[update]

I will try to explain this from a different angle. First the software is 
installed on a wide base of different windows OS. From XP to W10 on all
kind of computers. The software can be used on single desktops as on terminal
servers with a central LAN data pool (only a folder on a file-server).
It collects articles in a special way. So there are a lot of informations about
all kind of article data and also price informations from different vendors. 
So there is a big need for hiding/crypt this information to outsiders.

The current database is like an in-memory table of strings, doubles or long data values. 
Each row can contain a different set of columns. But most of the tables are like
a structured database table. The whole table data is crypted and zipped in one block.
Once loaded the whole data is expanded in memory where we can access this data very fast.
If an index is needed, we do this with a std::map inside the software.
We tried to compare our current table data against SQLite and EJDB. A file which contains
about half a million simple article data takes 3.5 MB in our data, 28MB in SQLite and 100 MB (in
several files) on EJDB. SQLite and EJDB shows the data in plain strings ore simple binary parts
of as example "double". So with a good editor you can match an article number with a price very
easy.

The software uses about 40 DLLs with several dependencys of third-party libs. So switching from
32 to 64 BIT is a challenge. Also does it not solve our problems with 32Bit terminal servers by our
client installations.

Going to a real database (like MySQL, MongoDB etc.) is a big challenge too as we freqently update our
data every month on the wide base of computers. There is not allway a internet connection to use a
real server client modell.

So what can we do?

Use SQLite or EJDB or something else and crypt our data in each field ?

Reprogramm our database so it uses smaller chunks of data which leafs on this and loaded the 
chunks on demand as they were neaded ?
Only the indexes are in memory. Manage the disk-data maybe with a B-Tree strategie.

Time is short. So reinventing the wheel does not help. What would you do or use in such
a situation ?

Comment: There is no 62 bit :|

Comment: @alDiablo: The C++ standard allows for 62 bit architectures.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: ;-) Next time you're in your garage with nothing to do, why not try to build one?

Comment: @Bathsheba unless someone already *has* built one, his first statement is still true. If someone has, by all means share the info, as I'd love to see it. Thanks for idea for a summer project. Gotta find something to do now that the kids are off to college.

Comment: It need to know more about task. I do not know is the sqlite or any else load all data into memory most probably it does not. But if you need quick acceess to data and data must be in memory try to use redis or switch to 62. Else use sqlite.

Comment: why not to use streaming in read-write operations (hold in memory only working chunk of your tables)? But you need an effective caching method and indexing.

Comment: I concur with @oklas. I ran into a similar problem regarding 32bit Apache (don't ask) and a mass of data being cached in-memory in our mod. Eventually growth pushed the limits of the in-memory caches and they would periodically breach, crashing the process on memory allocations (usually in the crypto libraries). I resolved the issue by standing up a side-by-side Redis server (64bit) on the same machine, setting up an all-keys LRU of significant size (8gB) then storing the cache data there. The performance reduction was marginal, but it has reaped huge benefit everywhere else. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> 400MB. Due to 32bit and memory fragmentation we can actually load maximum 2 such tables

Aren't you by any chance "loading" this tables by allocating a large chunk of memory and reading table content from disc into it? If so then you should switch to loading tables using smaller memory-mapped blocks (probably 4Mb each which corresponds to large memory page size). This way you should be able to utilize most of 3.5 Gb address space available for 32-bit program.